# Extracting hour from time stamp in R

Tags: r, time, extract

I would like to extract the hour of the day as numeric only from a column in R where the times are set up like this;

0:00
1:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
etc.

so I would like to only extract 10,11,12,13,etc...

I cannot find a way to do this in an efficient way.

Comment: Are you dealing with actual time formats? Please use `dput` to share a sample of your data.

Comment: I hope this is what you would like; "4:00", "5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00"), class = "factor")

Comment: You could do `sub("(.*):.*", "\\1", x)` or `sub(":.*", "", x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `gsub(x = timestamps, pattern = ":\d{2}", replacement = "")`  - you could also  `strsplit` on the colon, but that means you have to parse the resulting list.